# AJAX PHP video upload with convert to flv

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, video

I'm looking for some way to upload video via XHR, and video convert, my script in XHR looks like.

```
var files= $("#camera"+id).prop('files');
var file = files[0];
var cList= files.length;

$("#camera"+id).val('');
$("#textarea"+id).val('');

var fd = new FormData();

fd.append("file", file);
fd.append("name", name);
fd.append("desc", desc);
fd.append('id', id);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", "addUcChallenge.php", true);

xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e)
{



};


xhr.onload = function()
{

if(this.status == 200)
{
cList = 1;
//alert(xhr.responseText);
};

};

if(cList < 1)
{

}
else
{
xhr.send(fd);
}
```

When I tried to upload video is happen nothink, and when I wanted return some value of file nothing too, but photos are ok, and second think is that I don't know how to handle with video in PHP ( Upload, convert to flv ) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uploading you can use PlUploader [code example](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php) (that is used for large file uploading and make sure you have edited the max file uploading size in php.ini file if you are using php in backend) and for conversion you have to use the [FFMPEG](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ffmpeg-guide/)